# CSS: position: fixed; right margin

Tags: html, css, position

I might be doing something wrong, but I want to cut off my picture on the right side.

```
#background 
{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    right: 20em; 
    left: 20em; 
    top: 0em;  
    z-index: -1; 
    margin-right: 20em;
}
```

Background is a picture I want to cut off at the right side, `20em` in so I tried right margin without luck.

But with the fixed position I can only use left or right and top. Anyone got a smart fix for this?

[Image of website as it is](http://oi60.tinypic.com/21exdls.jpg)

EDIT: So right now the side is cut off on the left side. I want it to be cutted off on the right side too.

I have styled margins to be 20em from left and 20 em from the right. This white transparent picture should only cover that area.

I also need me reputation to post a picture, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a div with the good width, and then place the image in it, and apply css to the div:

```
div {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I removed the width and just added a margin-right. This seems to work!
The div idea made me realise what I had been doing right.

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

try to comment `width` and `right` params. It may help, but I am not sure that this you want

```
#background {
  /* widht: 100% */
  height: 100%; 
  position: fixed; 
  /* right: 20em; */
  left: 20em; 
  top: 0em;  
  z-index: -1; 
  margin-right: 20em;
}
```

http://cssdeck.com/labs/j7zbc2zs

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/eqE9J/135/

```
<div id="wrapper">   
    <img src="http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4017/4717107886_dcc1270a65_b.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    max-width:750px;
}
img{
    width:80%;
    padding:1%;
    border:1px solid red;
    position: fixed; 
    right: 20em; 
    top: 0; 
}
```